# How to read a pandas Series from a CSV file and squeeze

Tags: csv, pandas, series

I have a CSV file formatted as follows:

```
somefeature,anotherfeature,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,lastfeature
0,0,0,1,1,2,4,5
```

And I try to read it as a pandas Series (using pandas daily snapshot for Python 2.7).
I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
types = pd.Series.from_csv('csvfile.txt', index_col=False, header=0)
```

and:

```
types = pd.read_csv('csvfile.txt', index_col=False, header=0, squeeze=True)
```

But both just won't work: the first one gives a random result, and the second just imports a DataFrame without squeezing.

It seems like pandas can only recognize as a Series a CSV formatted as follows:

```
f1, value
f2, value2
f3, value3
```

But when the features keys are in the first row instead of column, pandas does not want to squeeze it.

Is there something else I can try? Is this behaviour intended?

/Edit: this question was written in 2013 and pertained to pandas v0.10 or 0.11.

Comment: This issue is ancient, the functionality was fixed almost a decade ago. Also, tell us the actual pandas version, `pd.__version__`, don't say "pandas daily snapshot for Python 2.7". Guessing it was pandas ~ 0.10-0.11

Comment: Yes indeed I asked this question in 2013, more than a decade ago...

Comment: Can you please tell us the actual pandas version (edit it into the question)? Guessing it was some dated snapshot between ~ 0.10-0.11. My point is this old question still shows up in search results today, even though CSV import to Series or DataFrame has been working fine for years; which is misleading.

Comment: @smci This was a long time ago, I do not remember the version, so.I just wrote what you guessed. I am not aware of any rule on SE that says questions should be modified over time to reflect the current state of knowledge, and I think it would be too unwieldy to do so, but I did it here since it didn't cost much.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a "rule", but as said this is the top incoming Google hit for *"How to read a pandas Series from a CSV file"*, even though it's an old issue fixed over a decade ago, so it continues to be misleading, and SO only continues to function as long as we community keep it accurate and somewhat fresh. Appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works. Squeeze still works, but it just won't work alone. The `index_col` needs to be set to zero as below

```
series = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv', header = None, index_col = 0, squeeze = True)
```

Comment: The `squeeze` parameter is deprecated as of version 1.4.0. Docs: "Append .squeeze("columns") to the call to read_csv to squeeze the data."

Answer (score 16):

Here is the way I've found:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('csvfile.txt', index_col=False, header=0);
serie = df.loc[0,:]
```

Seems like a bit stupid to me as Squeeze should already do this. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

/EDIT: Best way to do it:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('csvfile.txt', index_col=False, header=0);
serie = df.transpose()[0] # here we convert the DataFrame into a Serie
```

This is the most stable way to get a row-oriented CSV line into a pandas Series.

BTW, the squeeze=True argument is useless for now, because as of today (April 2013) it only works with row-oriented CSV files, see the official doc:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#returning-series

Comment: That did not work me! The transpose function turned my entire dataframe into some weird 2X2 object. I'm still trying to figure this out

Comment: this no longer works as ix was removed

Comment: @Tommy Thank you, I have updated my answer accordingly. These are old answers (10 years old this one), I'm not updating them all...

Answer (score 4):

```
In [28]: df = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv')

In [29]: df.ix[0]
Out[29]: 
somefeature       0
anotherfeature    0
f3                0
f4                1
f5                1
f6                2
f7                4
lastfeature       5
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: note, ix has been removed

Answer (score 2):

```
ds = pandas.read_csv('csvfile.csv', index_col=False, header=0);    
X = ds.iloc[:, :10] #ix deprecated
```

Answer (score 1):

As Pandas value selection logic is :

```
DataFrame -> Series=DataFrame[Column] -> Values=Series[Index]
```

So I suggest :

```
df=pandas.read_csv("csvfile.csv")
s=df[df.columns[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the answers above worked for me, here is another one, recreating the Series manually from the DataFrame.

```py
# create example series
series = pd.Series([0, 1, 2], index=["a", "b", "c"])
series.index.name = "idx"
print(series)
print()

# create csv
series_csv = series.to_csv()
print(series_csv)

# read csv
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(series_csv), index_col=0)
indx = df.index
vals = [df.iloc[i, 0] for i in range(len(indx))]
series_again = pd.Series(vals, index=indx)
print(series_again)
```

Output:

```
idx
a    0
b    1
c    2
dtype: int64

idx,0
a,0
b,1
c,2

idx
a    0
b    1
c    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas import read_csv


series = read_csv('csvfile.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True
```